# How to convert SharePoint classic page to SharePoint 2019 on-premises modern page?

Tags: sharepoint-server, modern-experience, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, classic-experience

Is there any way to convert classic page to modern page in **SharePoint 2019 On-Premises**? Actually, I have a classic page with added webparts and I want to convert that page into modern. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We are not able to convert Classic page to Modern Page in SharePoint 2019 on-premises. This behavior is by design.